# Scraping a website for specific data where URLs are inconsistent

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape http://www.narrpr.com/ for data, but I'm running into an issue. Most of the time, formatting URLs to access the specific pages you want to scrape is easy. However, in this instance, the URLs are formatted in the following fashion (for example):

`http://www.narrpr.com/homes/mo/independence/64055/2412-s-ellison-way/38664800-summary.aspx`

Where the number `38664800` appears to be some kind of unique ID.

When navigating the site manually, I enter `2412 S Ellison Way` into the form, which then redirects me to the URL above.

How can I programmatically reach the correct page without needing to know that ID? Alternatively, how can I get that ID?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use those tools? Why don't you use headless Chrome? Then you can do exactly what you're doing manually (along with other benefits).

Comment: @minboost I would prefer to scrape the data with Python.

Comment: You can use [Selenium.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

Comment: Have you tried just using a POST with the same data as if you had submitted the form?

Comment: Are you looking at the network tab? I recommend you read up on how to use Chrome dev tools.